# sed: replace multi-line block with standard input

Tags: text-processing, sed, stdin, here-document

**Given** is `input_file`:

```
1
2
START
foo
END
3
```

**Goal** is to replace content inside including `START` ... `END` block with multi-line content from stdin:

```
1
2
hello 
world
3
```

What I tried:

```
sed '/^START$/,/^END$/d;r /dev/stdin' input_file <<EOF 
hello
world
EOF
```

unfortunately results in

```
1
hello
world
2
3
```

I guess `r /dev/stdin` is invoked sequentially *after* `/^START$/,/^END$/d;` and just appends after first line.

Second try:

```
sed '/^START$/,/^END$/{d;r /dev/stdin
}' input_file <<EOF     
hello
world
EOF
```

prints

```
1
2
3
```

Why do above commands - especially last one - do print the wrong result? And how might I adjust these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first try, the address range is valid for the `d` only. The `r /dev/stdin` (append...) is done for the first line; thereafter, it runs into end-of-file.
In your second try, the script doesn't encounter the `r` command. `man sed`:

> ```
>   d      Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
> ```

So everything after the `d` command is lost (in the relevant address range); it just doesn't `r /dev/stdin`.

Try this to achieve yout target:

```
sed -e '/^START$/,/^END$/ { r /dev/stdin' -e';d};' file3 <<EOF 
hello
world
EOF

1
2
hello
world
3
```

read is the first thing when address range is met, then delete the address range.

Comment: Both your explanation and solution were extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is there any value in splitting the sed script to two `-e` expressions (except maybe for clarity and readability)?

Comment: the file name that is bein read has to be terminated, either by a `<NL>` char, or by a `'`; that's where the `-e` comes from. Try without!